# Getting problem in use method ? How to remove the error in use method?

Tags: r, tidyverse, feature-extraction

Following is the code I am using to extract image value using dataframe. But I am getting an error in last line of the code. Please let me know how to solve the issue?

```
library(raster)
library(gdalUtils)
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
setwd("C:/Users/phd-shanti/Downloads/trmm_daily18")
trmm_files <- list.files(,pattern=".nc4$",full.names = FALSE) # to read all files with the name nc4
trmm_stack <- stack(trmm_files, varname = "HQprecipitation")  # to stack multiple image together
crs(trmm_stack) <- CRS('+init=EPSG:4326')        # also it was rotated and geometry was set
trmm_stack_flip <- t(flip(trmm_stack, direction='y'))
setwd("D:/fire_work_cov/data/india_fire_points1mar_30may/20_02_cmbi_shp")
a <- list.files(pattern= '*.shp')
f<- read_sf("chotanagpur.shp") 
bb = as.data.frame(f)
g<- bb[,c("LATITUDE",'LONGITUDE')]
rasValue=extract(trmm_stack_flip , g)
```

I m getting error in last line?

> Error in UseMethod("extract_") :
> no applicable method for 'extract_' applied to an object of class "c('RasterBrick', 'Raster',
> 'RasterStackBrick', 'BasicRaster')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the `extract` function is called from the `tidyr` package. But here you want it to call it from the `raster` package. You can force it to call from it.

```
rasValue = raster::extract(trmm_stack_flip , g)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sir, I am getting NA , NA, NA and so on for all the 92 columns and row. The matrix contains no value after using the above code you suggested?

Comment: Your code worked.There is a liitle bit error in  g<- bb[,c("LATITUDE",'LONGITUDE')]. I have to reverse it as g<- bb[,c("LONGITUDE",'LATITDUE')],then it works properly. Thanks a lot.